# Which EXIF tag to store keyword/tag for a photo?

Tags: image-processing, tags, imagemagick, exif, exiftool

I am developing a photo gallery which will read/write EXIF tags. I will put photo title in the EXIF tag DocumentName and description in EXIF tag ImageDescription. I also plan to use the geo-tags. But what about photo tags/categories? I want to store a space-separated string of the tags a photo is tagged with in my system. Is there any EXIF tag that is normally used for this type of information? I could write my own (i.e. PhotoTags) but I guess that is not really of any use except for internally in my system (where this information is stored in a database anyway).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that will want to look into [IPTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPTC_Information_Interchange_Model) and/or [XMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) (not entirely clear over their relation) for storing metadata about images (such as keywords/tags, title, description and so on).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Im using ExifTool (http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) so I can write IPTC/XML as well. But I am still not sure which tag I should store keywords/categories/tags to.

Comment: Apparently the IPTC has a 'keyword' tag which some other applications seems to be using.

Comment: I use keywords field for storing keywords/tags. I also use the Headline field (title) and some other fields (if you grab an image off my website you can see how the data is stored in it for an example). ExifTool is an excellent tool btw.

Answer (score 5):

There's no EXIF tag for this, but there is an IPTC "keywords" tag.  JPEG can handle IPTC records, so there should be no problem.