# How can I access and change the tag description property of a JPEG image in the Windows 7 file explorer through the use of Python?

Tags: python, windows, file, tags, rename

I am having a difficult time understanding how I can change the Tags of a JPEG file through Python. The "Tags" I'm referring to are those under the description properties of any arbitrary file, where comments, subjects, and ratings would also be found. I am uncertain whether or not there is a .os function similar to the filename rename function which can do this, or if this kind of operation of changing the tags would fall under the category of JPEG Metadata/EXIFDATA manipulation.

Say, for example, I want to add 3 tags to a JPEG image through Python, those being the tags BLUE, SQUARE, and 9. Manually I would go to the file, access the description properties either by right-clicking the file to view its tags, or clicking the bottom bar menu, and click tags to then input BLUE, SQUARE, and 9 into the text box, with a semicolon after each individual tag. With Python, I would need a script that could inject those individual tags into the description properties of the JPEG to make the process less painful if I were to do this iteratively for multiple JPEG files.

I doubt this would require any heavy-handed knowledge of programing with Python, but at the same time the specificity of my issue seems to elude an easy resolution. I can't seem to find a semi-clear or straightforward answer, as I'm a bit of a greenhorn when it comes to programing with python in general.

Any help would be very, very useful. I am using Python 3.5.2. by the way.

Comment: Are you talking about metadata?

Comment: That's what I'm not entirely sure about. I know metadata can include things such as GPS locations, time of a picture being taken, type of camera a picture was taken with, things like that, yet I don't know if metadata also includes these windows properties like time the file was last messed with, file size, dimensions, rating, comments, and tags. I'm not sure if these properties are those that would be under the realm of "metadata"/EXIFDATA, or if it is under some other realm of information, since I don't know how to manipulate that information through python in the first place.

Comment: Yes that is metadata writing an answer right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, here is my revised answer.
So, all info in a jpg is metadata stored with an "id" number so for instance 0th is the discription area you are looking for heres a table.

```
0th:
283 = (720000, 10000)
296 = 2
34665 = 11444
306 = b'2011:08:22 21:39:05'
270 = b''
271 = b'OLYMPUS IMAGING CORP.'
272 = b'E-P1'
305 = b'Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows'
274 = 1
33432 = b'Robin Parmar'
282 = (720000, 10000)
315 = b'Robin Parmar'
```

source http://www.theatreofnoise.com/2016/10/how-to-retrieve-photo-metadata-in-python.html

So to change like the subject all you need to do is...

```
pip install piexif
```

This works with 2.7 & 3

```
import piexif

def insert_sample():
    zeroth_ifd = {270: "test"}
    exif_bytes = piexif.dump({"0th":zeroth_ifd})
    piexif.insert(exif_bytes,'img.jpg')

insert_sample()
```

Hope this helps :D
 Heres a list of all the ids

```
<< Inspect piexif >>

11 = ProcessingSoftware
18246 = Rating
18249 = RatingPercent
254 = NewSubfileType
255 = SubfileType
256 = ImageWidth
257 = ImageLength
258 = BitsPerSample
259 = Compression
262 = PhotometricInterpretation
263 = Threshholding
264 = CellWidth
265 = CellLength
266 = FillOrder
269 = DocumentName
270 = ImageDescription
271 = Make
272 = Model
273 = StripOffsets
274 = Orientation
277 = SamplesPerPixel
278 = RowsPerStrip
279 = StripByteCounts
282 = XResolution
283 = YResolution
284 = PlanarConfiguration
290 = GrayResponseUnit
291 = GrayResponseCurve
292 = T4Options
293 = T6Options
296 = ResolutionUnit
301 = TransferFunction
305 = Software
306 = DateTime
315 = Artist
316 = HostComputer
317 = Predictor
318 = WhitePoint
319 = PrimaryChromaticities
320 = ColorMap
321 = HalftoneHints
322 = TileWidth
323 = TileLength
324 = TileOffsets
325 = TileByteCounts
32781 = ImageID
330 = SubIFDs
332 = InkSet
333 = InkNames
334 = NumberOfInks
33421 = CFARepeatPatternDim
33422 = CFAPattern
33423 = BatteryLevel
33432 = Copyright
33434 = ExposureTime
336 = DotRange
337 = TargetPrinter
338 = ExtraSamples
339 = SampleFormat
340 = SMinSampleValue
341 = SMaxSampleValue
342 = TransferRange
343 = ClipPath
34377 = ImageResources
344 = XClipPathUnits
345 = YClipPathUnits
346 = Indexed
34665 = ExifTag
34675 = InterColorProfile
347 = JPEGTables
34853 = GPSTag
34857 = Interlace
34858 = TimeZoneOffset
34859 = SelfTimerMode
351 = OPIProxy
37387 = FlashEnergy
37388 = SpatialFrequencyResponse
37389 = Noise
37390 = FocalPlaneXResolution
37391 = FocalPlaneYResolution
37392 = FocalPlaneResolutionUnit
37393 = ImageNumber
37394 = SecurityClassification
37395 = ImageHistory
37397 = ExposureIndex
37398 = TIFFEPStandardID
37399 = SensingMethod
40091 = XPTitle
40092 = XPComment
40093 = XPAuthor
40094 = XPKeywords
40095 = XPSubject
50341 = PrintImageMatching
50706 = DNGVersion
50707 = DNGBackwardVersion
50708 = UniqueCameraModel
50709 = LocalizedCameraModel
50710 = CFAPlaneColor
50711 = CFALayout
50712 = LinearizationTable
50713 = BlackLevelRepeatDim
50714 = BlackLevel
50715 = BlackLevelDeltaH
50716 = BlackLevelDeltaV
50717 = WhiteLevel
50718 = DefaultScale
50719 = DefaultCropOrigin
50720 = DefaultCropSize
50721 = ColorMatrix1
50722 = ColorMatrix2
50723 = CameraCalibration1
50724 = CameraCalibration2
50725 = ReductionMatrix1
50726 = ReductionMatrix2
50727 = AnalogBalance
50728 = AsShotNeutral
50729 = AsShotWhiteXY
50730 = BaselineExposure
50731 = BaselineNoise
50732 = BaselineSharpness
50733 = BayerGreenSplit
50734 = LinearResponseLimit
50735 = CameraSerialNumber
50736 = LensInfo
50737 = ChromaBlurRadius
50738 = AntiAliasStrength
50739 = ShadowScale
50740 = DNGPrivateData
50741 = MakerNoteSafety
50778 = CalibrationIlluminant1
50779 = CalibrationIlluminant2
50780 = BestQualityScale
50781 = RawDataUniqueID
50827 = OriginalRawFileName
50828 = OriginalRawFileData
50829 = ActiveArea
50830 = MaskedAreas
50831 = AsShotICCProfile
50832 = AsShotPreProfileMatrix
50833 = CurrentICCProfile
50834 = CurrentPreProfileMatrix
50879 = ColorimetricReference
50931 = CameraCalibrationSignature
50932 = ProfileCalibrationSignature
50934 = AsShotProfileName
50935 = NoiseReductionApplied
50936 = ProfileName
50937 = ProfileHueSatMapDims
50938 = ProfileHueSatMapData1
50939 = ProfileHueSatMapData2
50940 = ProfileToneCurve
50941 = ProfileEmbedPolicy
50942 = ProfileCopyright
50964 = ForwardMatrix1
50965 = ForwardMatrix2
50966 = PreviewApplicationName
50967 = PreviewApplicationVersion
50968 = PreviewSettingsName
50969 = PreviewSettingsDigest
50970 = PreviewColorSpace
50971 = PreviewDateTime
50972 = RawImageDigest
50973 = OriginalRawFileDigest
50974 = SubTileBlockSize
50975 = RowInterleaveFactor
50981 = ProfileLookTableDims
50982 = ProfileLookTableData
51008 = OpcodeList1
51009 = OpcodeList2
51022 = OpcodeList3
51041 = NoiseProfile
512 = JPEGProc
513 = JPEGInterchangeFormat
514 = JPEGInterchangeFormatLength
515 = JPEGRestartInterval
517 = JPEGLosslessPredictors
518 = JPEGPointTransforms
519 = JPEGQTables
520 = JPEGDCTables
521 = JPEGACTables
529 = YCbCrCoefficients
530 = YCbCrSubSampling
531 = YCbCrPositioning
532 = ReferenceBlackWhite
60606 = ZZZTestSlong1
60607 = ZZZTestSlong2
700 = XMLPacket
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. I believe I understand that this is meant to allow for the development of custom tags within the EXIFDATA structure of JPEG image. For my particular problem, however, I am not so much interested in developing tags as complex as those demonstrated in the post you referenced as I am in being able to add a list of tags to a JPEG image that could be viewable through the windows file explorer, like other viewable properties such as file size and dimensions.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean im going to look into this more. This might be a thing that requires using win32

Comment: Also, from what I can tell, I do not know if the "user comment" tag is a tag referring to the structuring of tagged information within the EXIFdata of an image, as opposed to the "comment"  under properties a JPEG image can that is editable through the windows file explorer. I do not know if these two things are the same. If they are the same "comment", I would think those tags, such as the skin type, complexion, location, etc would end up in the comment property of a particular JPEG image, which could be viewable through windows explorer.

Comment: Yes thank you for looking more into this. It's a very particular problem that I'm uncertain has a straightforward answer. The post you referenced did help me understand more about the topic of EXIFDATA manipulation, so I appreciate that.

Comment: I think I figured it out going to rewrite my answer but here's a sneak peak http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html

Comment: It's a shame how hard it is to edit this data, considering how old it is.

Comment: Awesome, this does exactly what I need. The only issue is which of the id numbers refers to the "Tags" of the file. I tested it with the "Subject" Id 270 and got exactly what I hoped for, with the text "test" popping up under the subject of my tester image. Do you know off hand which Id number that is, or is there even one that exists for "Tags"?

Comment: I'll find out in a sec.

Comment: For the tags tab, it's 34665. Please mark my answer as correct if this helped you. =)

Comment: I'm testing it with 34665, but for whatever reason the Tags tab does not update to what I inserted with the Python code. I'm not sure why it isn't updating. It works with subject, strangely enough.

Comment: Sorry my mistake XD. I was testing it a while ago and put in the value test over windows. So when I did this I thought it worked. Let me mess with this more...

Comment: There isn't a exif number for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936937/which-exif-tag-to-store-keyword-tag-for-a-photo

Comment: https://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2014/06/python-reading-exif-and-iptc-tags-from.html they have examples on how to do it the other way that should work

Comment: Drat. Oh well. You've helped me immensely though. I'll see what I can do with what I've got. Thank you very much for your help, it's been very informative.

Comment: No problem have a nice day.